# Yesod javascript formatting

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am working on debugging some javascript code that is generated in Yesod. Yesod generates javascript files with each function on one line which makes it impossible to set break points within the function. Is there a way to change this behavior so that the javascript preserves formatting for debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am currently using yesod 0.9, but I bet his will work in other versions as well.

Look in your Foundation.hs for:

```
addStaticContent = addStaticContentExternal minifym base64md5 Settings.staticDir 
                                            (StaticR . flip StaticRoute [])
```

and change it to:

```
addStaticContent = addStaticContentExternal (\bs -> Right bs) base64md5 Settings.staticDir
                                            (StaticR . flip StaticRoute [])
```

I changed minifym -> (\bs -> Right bs) which just wraps the in coming content, javascript in our case, and returned. Or dave4420 points out below just replace minifym with (\bs -> Right bs) [point free style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) equivalent Right.
This should make your javascript preserve its format.

Comment: Why `(\bs -> Right bs)` and not simply `Right`?

Comment: Good point added as an alternative with a link to the haskell wiki on point free style.

Comment: Sure, but the original code uses `minify` rather than `(\bs -> minify bs)`. I just don't see how the usual arguments against using point free style --- that it is difficult to understand and difficult to modify --- apply in this case.

Comment: Good to know there is a programmatic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `addStaticContent` function in your `Foundation` file treats `.js` files as a special case, which lets you enable or disable minification by passing a different minification function as the first argument (`Right` leaving the file contents untouched).

Additionally, if you use Google Chrome for Javascript debugging, you can use the pretty-print button to debug minified Javascript, which looks like this:

[image: pretty-print button]

This gives you manageable Javascript syntax.

Javascript is the exception to the rule that Yesod minifies everything that gets processed by special purpose Shakespeare languages. It is in general not possible to get a non-minifed representation of HTML and CSS with the current implementation of Shakespeare.

Comment: I think it's more of a problem with minified javascript than with a particular framework. This problem also exists in C/C++/Java/C#/etc and most debuggers don't have similarly convenient workarounds.

Comment: "The fact that Yesod imposes very strict restrictions on how you have to treat your data is the reason why many developers are considering alternative solutions"...huh?

Comment: This answer is patently false. Yesod itself doesn't hardcode minification *anywhere*. Davorak's answer is correct, yours is not. The ridiculous last sentence in your answer sounds like you're trying to discredit Yesod.

Comment: Yesod **does** hardcode minification into other template languages (Hamlet, Cassius, ...), and the quirks with these languages **have** lead to numerous blog posts etc. Julius seems to be the exception here; I honestly thought that it did minification as well, since a function for external static content is the last place I would have looked for a JS minifier. I sincerely apologize for my mistake, but had the question been about HTML instead of Javascript, what would you have said then?

Comment: A mistake is fine, but it's the FUD-sounding answer that upsets me. I haven't seen these "numerous blog posts" you speak of, or the flocks of people leaving Yesod because one of its dependencies minifies data. Hamlet has had settings in the past to turn off minification, and no one complained when they were removed. As for leaving Yesod because Lucius minifies CSS... neither Happstack nor Snap even provide a CSS template language, so that's just ridiculous.

Comment: I kept the paragraph that you regard as being "FUD" so that your comment would make sense, and although I think that I managed to keep it pretty objective, I will remove it if you think that it discredits Yesod unjustly. Thanks for your constructive criticism!

Comment: The current version looks fine to me, thank you for the modification. As far as your actual criticism: all the code is already in Hamlet to produce non-minified output, it's just a matter of exposing the setting to the user. I have a general objection to doing so, since adding whitespace can change semantics (I've had the same discussion with clients about XML/XSLT). For CSS, I don't think adding whitespace would be difficult, if anyone actually wanted it. Though this discussion would make more sense on a mailing list.